# Is there a best practice to prevent the user of my Angular SPA to manipulate the Form-Data in a Request before it is sent to the server

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, security, google-developer-tools

My **Angular** (Version 5) app is secured with a JWT Token and AuthGuards. In theory a user is able to manipulate form data with Chromes Developer Tools before the aggregated form values are sent to the server. Are there **nowadays** **new good practices** to prevent this on client side and therefore I can assume that the data sent over with https to the server can be trusted ?

This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116234/best-ways-to-secure-form-data-from-malicious-users-wielding-firebug) addresses the problem:  A server side session in combination with validation is recommended there. But in a Restful Architecture there is no session anymore and we can´t prevent all combinations of manipulation attempts by using validations on server side. Therefore I am looking for a convenient client side solution, that makes it uncomfortable for the ***normal*** user to manipulate with developer tools. Also I know that there can´t be 100% trustful Client implementation. But complicating the manipulation attempts would be nice trade-off.

Comment: Creating a hash over the data to submit would complicate data manipulation a bit since you would also have to create the hash for the manipulated data.

Comment: You don't have to prevent all combinations of manipulation attempts. Just check if the given combination makes sense and if the user is allowed to do this operation. Then do it.

Comment: 100% trustful client is not practically achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating HttpClient interceptors (see https://angular.io/guide/http), which will be automatically invoked for each HTTP request (including the ones initiated by forms). In those interceptors, you can implement some business logic to ensure that the data was not being manipulated by the user.

Comment: This would still allow the request to be modified, _after_ the interceptor has been ran.

Comment: Using the Http-Interceptor approach in conjunction with the suggestion of https://stackoverflow.com/users/332419/dormilich to create hashes would definitely make it more complicate for the user to manipulate, what I asked for. Therefore thanks to Yakov and Dormilich. I´ll try this pattern.